# Значення слова "плавочки"

Tags: значення-слів

Прочитав вірш "Мана" Миколи Костомарова, де зустрів такі рядки:

> Є в нас плесо; осокою
>   Поросло кругом;
>   Посередині **плавочки**
>   Плавають рядком.

Цікавить значення слова "плавочки", адже такого слова немає в СУМі, а при введені його в пошуку Гугл видає відеокліп Ольги Полякової, що аж ніяк не може бути тим, що потрібно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сьогодні наткнувся на [цю статтю (В. М. Русанівський, «Історія української літературної мови», Київ, «Артек», 2001, с. 167)](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Rusanivskyy_VM/Istoriia_ukrainskoi_literaturnoi_movy.pdf#page=84), де дається відповідь на питання, яке я задав 4 місяці тому:

> У поетів-романтиків була тенденція до нормалізації мови української
>   літератури. Спеціально уникаю тут терміна «літературна мова», бо про
>   неї можна говорити тільки після творчості Т. Шевченка. Зразком чистоти
>   мови був, звичайно, фольклор. І поети романтики, як і безіменні творці
>   фольклору, намагалися уникати вузько локальних слів. Та стежити за цим
>   було дуже важко, тому локалізми, звичайно, з'являлися. Це, скажімо, у
>   І. Галки рябець «шуліка», увійнятися «вгамуватися», ізгарб
>   «сніговиця», «хуртовина», меріти «мріти», оцваньок «неньок», музувіри
>   «турки», **плавочки «качки»**, утворний «стрункий», «гарний» та ін. У
>   галузі морфології А. Могила навіть допускає стилізацію під особливості
>   західноукраїнської народної мови. Так, у вірші «Думка червонорусця»
>   знаходимо: Край в цю пору згадує мі ся частенько; Хто тя, краю милий,
>   хто по волі кине? Хто к ті із чужини, краю, не полине (АМІГ, 56).

Гадаю, що саме качки плавали рядком, а не трясовина.

Answer (score 4):

Очевидно, в даному вірші йде мова про [ПЛАВ](http://sum.in.ua/s/plav):

> 3. Сміття, різні предмети, що пливуть по річці суцільним потоком (звичайно під час повені). Я пливу за водою.. І плав пливе. Пропливають лози, верби, в'язи, тополі у воді (Олександр Довженко, Зачарована Десна, 1957, 476);  * У порівняннях. Злилось як плав (Словник Грінченка).
> 4. Невеликі мулувато-торф'янисті плавучі утворення з коренів і стебел очерету, рогозу, вкриті рослинами. Кругом обняла його [хутір] річка з зеленими плавами, лозами й очеретами (Пантелеймон Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 49); Плави постійно або періодично плавають, вони відокремлені від берегів або з'єднані з ними (Ботанічний журнал, X, 3, 1953, 34).
> 5. Ділянка трясовини, де під шаром рослинності є вода. Вночі через болото переходила [Оленка], в плаву провалилася (Костянтин Гордієнко, Діти.., 1937, 44).

На мою думку, письменник утворив від слова **плав** за допомогою зменшувально-пестливого суфікса [-очк-](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81) **плавочки**. Наймовірніше, що **плав** вживається в даному контексті у 4 значенні.